# Auto-match footer height with body in CSS?

Tags: css, footer

My website looks great right now. Except on iPhone, when held upright, there is a big ugly white space between my content and the footer. I want the footer to be right under the content all the time, but at the same time keep the right look everywhere. How can I make the footer automatically stretch up to that content and have the same color as the footer to fill the rest of the page?

Here's my code:

```
/********************
     Page Base 
********************/

html, body { 
height: 100%; 
width: 100%; 
overflow-x: hidden;  
margin:0; 
padding:0;
font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px; 
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; 
font-smoothing: antialiased; 
}

img, a {
border:none;
outline: none;
}

#wrapper{ 
min-height:100%;
max-height:950px;

position:relative; 
}

#header { 
width: 100%;  
height:145px; 
background-color: #fff; 
position: relative;

}   

#shadow { 
width: 1920px;  
height:145px; 
background-image:url(images/h_shadow.png);
position: relative;
z-index:-1;
margin-top:-98px;

}   

#content { 
height:auto;
position:relative;
padding:770px; 
padding-bottom:35px; 
width:100%;
display:none;
z-index:-2;
}

.contentbox{
    width:3000px;
    height:100%;
    margin-top:-770px;
    padding:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    background:fff;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    margin-left:2000px;
}

#footer { 
width:100%; 
height:72px; 
position:absolute; 
bottom:0; 
left:0; 
background:#222; 
margin:0; 
padding:0; 
}

.clear {
clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to see your html, but if you position your footer relatively, then it will automatically display at the bottom, right underneath whatever is above it. And you can just set the background of your `body` to the same color of your footer.